# How to Increase the Response/Request Timeout on IIS 7, using web.config file on a shared hosting

Tags: iis, timeout

I am trying to increase the Response timeout for IIS7-FastCGI-PHP based application using web.config file on my shared hosting account.
I want to do this because, if my script takes more than 30~40 seconds to execute, IIS7 is returning **500 Internal server error**. 
Any script that takes more than 30~40 seconds, it returns **500 internal server error**. 
I tried with ASP script also, but the same result.

I have access to Web.config file only, so i tried below methods without any positive results.
I added

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="120">
</system.web>
```

The above directive is for IIS6 version i think, so it did not make any effect.
Is there any alternative for the above directive in IIS7?, i did not find any.

Then i tried with below tags and related child like cgi and fastCgi, but no effects.

```
<system.webServer>
</system.webServer>
```

Any solutions or suggestions on how to increase the Timeout?, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FastCGI and PHP both have their own timeout settings that also affect this. See this blog post on IIS.Net for details:

http://blogs.iis.net/donraman/archive/2010/02/08/troubleshoot-my-php-script-is-timing-out.aspx

The problem you are going to have is that some of these things (like the FastCGI configuration section) are done (exclusively if I remember correctly) at the `applicationHost.config` file level, not in the `web.config` file. You would need to talk to your hosting provider to increase the timeouts.